# Get all cells in a sheet with A1 notation when the sheet's name conflicts with a cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Using the new v4 Google Sheets API, is it possible to get a range of all cells in a spreadsheet when it conflicts with a cell in A1 notation ?

For example, I have a sheet called `A001`.

1. `A001!A1:D3` - Get range A1-D3 from sheet named A001
2. `Some-other-sheet` - Get all cells from a sheet called "Some-other-sheet"
3. `A001` - instead of getting all cells from a sheet called A001, it gets cell A1 from the first visible sheet.

So I'm basically asking about case #3. Is it possible to get all range of A001 ? (not knowing the range in advance of course)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, parsing as a cell or a named range will take precedence over a sheet name.  You can workaround this by choosing a suitably large range and requesting that, e.g: `A001!A:ZZZ` -- that will request all rows in column `A` through column `ZZZ` in sheet `A001`.  The response will only include the last row/col where data actually exists.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, use single quotes around the sheet name, like this:

`'A001'`

> If the sheet name has spaces or starts with a bracket, surround the sheet name with single quotes ('), e.g 'Sheet One'!A1:B2. For simplicity, it is safe to always surround the sheet name with single quotes.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts